# Node-curl ошибка при установке

Tags: node.js

Ребят выручайте, вобщем разработал проект на дом. ПК, там использовал 
express 3.5.x
node.js v0.10.25

Попросил хостеров установить express и node.js
Поставили
express 4.2.0
node.js v0.11.14-pre

Начал разворачивать проект и столкнулся с рядом проблем. Нужно немного переписать под новые версии скрипт.

При установки

```
npm install node-curl
```

Пишет

```
root@p215721:/var/www/nodejs/data/progect# npm install node-curl
|
> node-curl@0.3.1 install /var/www/nodejs/data/progect/node_modules/node-curl
> sh src/generate_curl_options_list.sh && (node-gyp rebuild || node-waf configure build)

extract constants from /usr/include/curl/curl.h
generate src/integer_options.h
generate src/string_options.h
generate src/integer_infos.h
generate src/string_infos.h
generate src/double_infos.h
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:66:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:152:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:95:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:720:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:994:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1160:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.close (net.js:461:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab085.20
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/nodejs/data/progect/node_modules/node-curl
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
sh: node-waf: not found
npm ERR! node-curl@0.3.1 install: `sh src/generate_curl_options_list.sh && (node-gyp rebuild || node-waf configure build)`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-curl@0.3.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-curl package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     sh src/generate_curl_options_list.sh && (node-gyp rebuild || node-waf configure build)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-curl
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab085.20
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-curl"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/nodejs/data/progect
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.14-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.16
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nodejs/data/progect/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Как я понял из за версии node.js все проблемы, что можно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите на этот [модуль](https://github.com/visionmedia/n). Если вы сможете его глобально установить, то у вас появится возможность устанавливать и использовать разные версии node.js. Или, не исключено, что модули надо ставить под root-ом

Comment: я под рутом и ставлю, просто нубас в администрировании серверов.
Попробую поставить "n". Но может быть у кого то будут и другие варианты, было бы супер подогнать под свежую версию node.js

npm n помог, установил стабильную node.js (0.10.29) и установился node-curl

Спасибо!!